# Has the 25 Amendment Inability Clause ever been used to remove POTUS

Tags: united-states, president, constitution, twenty-fifth-amendment

The 25th Amendment of the US constitution is in the top of my mind. This deals with succession in the event of the resignation, death, or incapacity of POTUS. It also allows for temporary incapacity, during which the VP may step in as acting POTUS.

Several times the POTUS has died in office. One resigned. Grover Clevland was temporarily incapacitated during recovery from surgery. Has any previous POTUS been permanently removed due to incapacity?

Comment: Several presidents have used the 25th for different things when they need the VP to take over temporarily. Are you asking about if it has ever been used to remove a president against their will?

Comment: What research have you done into this already? Have you, for example, [checked Wikipedia's article on the 25th Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Invocations_and_considered_invocations)?

Answer (score 6):

The 25th was ratified in July 1965.  Since then one President has resigned the office (Nixon) with Ford completing Nixon's term. All the others have either served two full terms, or been defeated after one term.

The 25th has been invoked in times of temporary incapacity (for example when Regan was shot or when Bush had surgery) It has never been used to remove a President due to incapacity. Nor has it ever been invoked against a president against their will.

Prior to 1965 there was no constitutional mechanism to remove a President who was incapacitated. Woodrow Wilson suffered a severe stroke in 1919 and spent the last year of his presidency with significant illness, but remained as President.